# How session works in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, session, session-cookies

I Learn about session in rails. Most of the reference says that, the following is the way to create a session.

Example:

```
session[:id]=user.id
```

Session is a global hash. My doubt is, if session is a global hash, then If more than one user try's to login, then the session variable gets 
overwrite or not ? Because, there will be only one global hash. So, if millions of user gets login, then how the same "session[:id]" hold
all the users sessions. Is it possible to store more than one value in a single variable. And also how to delete a session for a particular
user. So, how session is handled in rails?

Comment: @7stud Why thread comes here ?

Comment: `session` is NOT a global hash. It's a METHOD that returns a new hash in the context of each request.

Comment: @Aetherus After returning the new hash, Is it maintains any data about logged in user in server side?

Comment: I just gave an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`session` is not a global hash. It's a method that returns a new hash in the context of each request. How that hash is created depends on the underlying session store.

Let's take a look at 2 typical session stores.

**Encrypted cookie store**

This is the default session store of Rails applications. Rails serializes then encrypts the whole session hashes into cookies, and stores those cookies on the clients (e.g. browsers). Each time a request hits Rails app, Rails decrypts then deserializes that session cookie to a hash. That hash is what the method `session` returns.

**Redis session store**

This session store is not shipped with Rails. It's a separate gem.

With this session store, Rails serializes the session, gives it an ID (called session ID), and stores the ID-hash pair into Redis. Rails then set the session ID to cookie and send that cookie to the client. Each time a request hits Rails app, Rails retrieves the session ID from the cookie, gets the serialized session associated with that session ID from Redis, and deserializes that into a hash. That hash is what the method `session` returns.

Comment: Thanks. I understood. But when I delete the session as "session[:id]=nil", then how it deletes the session cookies stored in client side.

Comment: Doesn't need to delete the client's cookie.  His/her cookie will no longer match with any key on the server and they'll be asked to login again etc.

Comment: If something changes in a session, Rails simply serializes and stores that session again.

Answer (score 1):

> Most applications need to keep track of certain state of a particular
>   user. This could be the contents of a shopping basket or the user id
>   of the currently logged in user...Rails will create a new session automatically if a new user
>   accesses the application. It will load an existing session if the user
>   has already used the application.
>
> A session usually consists of a hash of values and a session id,
>   usually a 32-character string, to identify the hash. Every cookie sent
>   to the client's browser includes the session id. And the other way
>   round: the browser will send it to the server on every request from
>   the client.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html

In other words, each unique user has their own session hash.  "Global" means that the session hash can be accessed inside any action/method.

Comment: So, session is only on client side. Not in server side. So there is no session maintained in server. Is is right? If it is right then what is the security. After the session hash is sent to the client, then it is possible to access the server form client whenever we want, Until I safely have the session hash.

Comment: After reading the quote, that is your interpretation?  The client side has no idea that the Ruby language has even been invented yet.  Is it really your belief that `session[:id] = user.id` is client side code, e.g. javascript?

Comment: As per the quote ` It will load an existing session if the user has already used the application.`. From where it is loaded. There is only one variable named "session[:id]". It gets overwritten when the second users logs in. Then how it is possible to maintains the 1st user id and its hash ?

Comment: No. Session[:id] = user.id is not only to client side. I expect it also maintains some session details for logged in users in server side.

Comment: *From where it is loaded.* =>  `session = all_sessions[session_id_from_cookie_in_client_request]; all_sessions[new_unique_session_id] = {} if not session`

Comment: Is it your belief that a variable named `session_id_from_cookie_in_client_request` is an actual variable name in Rails?

Comment: No. It shows error on all_sessions. It didn't say as argument error.

Comment: @mrg: Right, because I made up all those variable names so that it would be clear what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

As 7stud stated, all sessions are created on a user by user basis.  Since HTTP is a "stateless" protocol, you would potentially need someone to enter their login information everytime they wanted to look at a new page or even refresh the existing one.  This is where sessions comes in.  In Rails, each session is assigned a unique session id (a 32 character string of random hex numbers) when it's created and a cookie containing this id is then sent to the client's browser.  From that point on, every request from the browser sends the session id back to the server thus maintaining continuity.  Normal guidelines to follow are you should only keep track of the bare minimum in a session such as info to determine the current user (like a primary key etc.).

Comment: So, there is no session details maintained in server side. Except the request comes from the user. Is it right?

Comment: The unique ID generated by your server is stored on the server-side and in the user's browser as a cookie.  Then each time a user checks a new page on your server, the unique id is compared between your server's key and it matches the two.

Comment: Where the Unique ID is stored.

Comment: @bkunzi01: I think in rails, by default, the entire session is stored in a cookie. Not only id.

Comment: Yes sergio sorry if I made it sound like it was just a key!  Thanks for your rails contributions thus far I live off your Q&A lol.

Comment: For Ex: If 10 users are logged in, How the server identify those request and where it keeps data about logged in users?

Comment: @mrg: with session cookie storage, server simply decrypts the cookie from the request and there is your session object. Server doesn't keep data about logged in users.

Comment: So, How to delete a session.

Comment: How "session={}" deletes the cookies stored in client side?. Because we execute it in server side.

Comment: No such reference gives about this. They simply says session creation and deletion.

Comment: Let me spell things out for you: 1) It is possible for sever side code to store information between requests such as a unique id.  All popular server side languages, e.g. php, ruby, python, perl, etc. provide that feature with an easy to use API.  2) It is possible for server side code to delete cookies.  Given those two possibilities, can you not reason out that it is possible for Rails to use a scheme to identify users by the information in their request, then look up stored information related to that user, and then delete the users information when the time comes?

Comment: You can reset a user's entire session by adding "reset session" to a controller action, you can delete the session via "session.delete :id" or whatever key you've already set.

Comment: I gave you a code example of how such a scheme would work.